# Vuejs v-for loop with tag combination

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I want to loop two list tags for every loop of v-for without looping ul. Is there any internal looping available in vuejs to escape the ul tag by getting looped or is there any other method.

```
<ul id="example-1" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.message">
  <li >
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
  <li>
   {{ item.text}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'Foo', text: "baz" },
      { message: 'Bar', text: "quz" }
    ]
  }
})
```

The obvious result that i can get is :

Foo

Bar

baz

quz

The result That i need:

Foo

baz

Bar

quz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop on a `<template>` tag.

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <template v-for="item in items">
    <li>
      {{ item.message }}
    </li>
    <li>
     {{ item.text}}
    </li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

If you are using **Vue <= 2.x**, then you will need to assign keys to the inner elements, since templates cannot be keyed.

If you are using **Vue 3.x**, then you should assign a key to the `<template>`. This is a [breaking change](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/key-attribute.html#overview) from earlier releases.

Comment: I'm using Vue3 and Vue-cli and when I try to key children elements of `<template v-for=...>` I get an error `VueCompilerError: <template v-for> key should be placed on the <template> tag`.  I previously commented on this github issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6470

Comment: Thanks, @NathanGoings. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Wow!  How did I miss that "breaking change"!  Thanks for that link.